# Is it useful to have your company name as an <h1> on every page?

Tags: seo

I saw a (quite okay) website where every page has the logo/title of the company as an . I was wondering if that is actually usefull or just ruining your SE(o)-score?

The full HTML line is
`<h1 class="Logo"><a href="/" class="Logo">Company name here</a></h1>`

And I got to add: Not the , but the  gets, via CSS, updated with a background image.

Comment: This is very easily googled. I entered your exact title and got plenty results

Comment: Correct, but I wanted some (fresh) user inputs to the situation.